# Call await in a callback inside an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, functional-programming, async-await

Here is some code (it's an over-simplified example, I know it is dumb):

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function test() {
    [1, 2, 3].map(() => {
        console.log('test');
        await sleep(1000);
    });
}
test();
```

The objective is to:

1. display `test` then wait one second
2. then display `test` then wait one second
3. then display `test` then wait one second

But running this code results in a failure:

> await is a reserved word

I know I can do fix it by using a for loop:

```
async function test() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log('test');
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

But is there a way to do it in a more "functional" way. I mean, can I avoid the `for` loop and await inside a map?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a library like bluebird?

Comment: A bit off-topic but how do you use async with node.js, is there a lib for it?

Comment: @this.lau_ I use babel

Comment: @this.lau_ If you are fine with the none LTS version then it is supported since 7.6 or 8.x. Starting with October 2017, you have it in the LTS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const result = await [1, 2, 3].reduce(async function(prom, v){   
    const result= await prom;
    await sleep(1000);
    result.push(v);
    return result;
 }, Promise.resolve([]));
```

You could reduce to create a promise chain. However in your simplyfied case:

```
(a=b=>(b==2||(console.log("test"),setTimeout(a,1000,b+1))))(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If a library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) is an option then you could write:

```
'use strict'
const Promise = require('bluebird')


async function test() {
  return Promise.mapSeries([1, 2, 3], async (idx) => {
    console.log('test: ' + idx);
    await Promise.delay(1000)
  });
}
test();
```